# Why does this Visual Studio timer component work in design time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

In .Net windows form application, there is a timer in one of the form which is enabled. The below code is the handle:

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ( !CheckLock())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No lock found.");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No lock found.");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The lock is an usb  hardware lock. Suprisingly the code shows this pops up message in the **design time** (in the VS 2010 IDE) if I take out the lock.

Does anyone know what the reason is?

Comment: Is it showing even when you stopped debugging?

Comment: Exactly when the application is not debugged or run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty normal, your code can run at design time as well.  The context of this method is unclear, but good odds that you'll get the timer to tick when you, for example, inherit the Form class in which this method is present.  Or when you have this code in a UserControl and you dropped it on a form.

This is the primary way in which the designer provides the WYSIWYG appearance.  Like setting the BackgroundImage property of a control immediately shows you the image in the designer as well.  In other words, both the BackgroundImage property setter and the control's OnPaintBackground() method are executing at design time.  The basic rule is that any code in the *base class* can run at design time.  The code that you add to the derived class does not.

Fixing it is easy, use the DesignTime property to prevent the timer from being active at design time.  Something like this:

```
    timer2.Enabled = !this.DesignTime;    // Instead of true
```

Comment: Yes this method is in a class which inherits from Form class. Other classes also inherit from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below condition on the code that you don't want to run in design mode:

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
// Code here only executes when running, not in design mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the timer also runs in design time.
You should test whether the code is running in DesignMode:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( this.DesignMode ) return; 

    try
    {
        if ( !CheckLock())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No lock found.");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No lock found.");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Confer to [Controls, properties, events and timers running in design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491032/controls-properties-events-and-timers-running-in-design-time)
and [Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164159.aspx) for more background information.